# React build failed to minify the bundle. error from UglifyJs

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, uglifyjs

My react app has randomly stopped working when i try and do a build with:

```
npm run-script build
```

The error is:

> Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.4f3a37aa.js from UglifyJs
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at Array.push ()
> at C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\scripts\build.js:120:23
> at C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:269:13
> at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:375:38)
> at C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:262:10
> at C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:368:12
> at next (C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
> at Compiler. (C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
> at next (C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:220:14)
> at C:\Mist_Applications_Ltd\ASIRTAPORTAL\ASIRTAPORTAL\ClientApp\node_modules\sw-precache-webpack-plugin\lib\index.js:98:18

The webpack section of my package json looks like this:

[image]

I have tried so much stuff and just dont understand why things have suddenly stoped working!

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I got the same issue. It just stopped working

Comment: are you using materialui icons?